# return blank cell instead of 30/12/1899 error

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have 2 googlesheets array formula
one  gives latest date from a range

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(LARGE(((Stock!$J$2:$J$900000)*(-- (Stock!$H$2:$H$900000="study"))),1)))
```

the other one gives second latest date

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(LARGE(((Stock!$J$2:$J$900000)*(--(Stock!$H$2:$H$900000="study"))),2)))
```

the formulas work well but when the reference cell is blank it gives 30/12/1899, I want to get blank cell

Answer (score 1):

maybe,

```
IF(<your long formula>="30/12/1899", "", <your long formula>)
```

If you don't wan't to execute the same thing twice you could put your function in another cell, than something likes this:

```
IF(<other with function result>="30/12/1899", "", <other with function result>)
```

haven't tested it though.